# Nunit - XML based Data provider

Tags: web-services, testing, automation, nunit, automated-tests

- I have used TestNG & Selenium for Test UI Automation
- For .NET web services testing http web requests can be used to do functional testing
- Has any one tried web services automation using Nunit ? Does it support passing data parameters in XML (Data Driven Testing) like TestNG?

Any experience/guidelines with WCF / ASPX 2.0 Web services functional test automation using Nunit if you can share would be helpful

Thanks,

Siva

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I like to think about Web Services, WCF Services as another kind of interface to my business logic. And I only unit test my logic.

There is nothing specific in NUnit for testing WCF or Web Services.

Comment: +1 since I agree with you. :) Note though that the OP did (correctly) state that this was for functional testing.

Comment: Thanks folks, I was looking at Nunit from test automation perspective. Right direction probably is, I need to look at SOAPUI /VSTT for functional test automation of web services.